# How to write a global store plugin?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, plugins, vuejs3, store

I'm trying to make a reactive `$store` object globally available via plugin but am failing to make it work.

`store.ts`:

```
import {reactive} from "vue";

export default {
    install: (app:any, options:any) => {

        app.config.globalProperties.$store = reactive({})
    }
}
```

`main.ts`:

```
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import app from "@/vue/app.vue";
import store from "@/scripts/store";

createApp(app)
    .use(store)
    .mount("#app");
```

Now I would expect for the plugin to be usable in all components, but `$store` stays an `undeclared variable`, when I try to use it in the `<script setup>` tag inside a component.

Comment: It doesn't work this way. globalProperties exposes a property to a template and has limited applications, e.g. filters. It would be usable in component script if it were exposed to `window`. You may notice that nobody does that to avoid explicit imports in modern web apps because it's a terrible practice

Comment: What about using a pinia store https://pinia.vuejs.org/ ?

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a bad idea to centralize the state instead of having it distributed among components, it is highly inadvisable to have **global references**.

Instead global reference, creating event buses or a long chain of emits, the classic option in this framework is the Flux pattern. Currently the simplest implementation of Flux in Vue and the one officially recommended is [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html). It exactly meets your requirement in a very simple way. It has very good typescript support and you just have to import the stores you need where you need them and they will reactively maintain state throughout the app.